# Retrieving an inbound message using the Mandrill API

Tags: c#, mandrill

I'm trying to retrieve inbound messages from the API on Mandrill, but when I call the sendRaw method, the API fails with an error saying I need to specify a raw message value.  I guess the SendRaw is sending the message I specify, rather than returning the message I request?

```
static async Task<string> SendRaw(string key)//,string )
    {
        string sendRaw = mandrillAPI + "inbound/send-raw.json";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(sendRaw);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(key);
        string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return s;
    }
```

The raw message is the content I'm trying to retrieve, so I don't see how I can supply it.

Is there a way to retrieve messages from the server using the API?  And if that is the wrong way to say it...lets put it this way: I set up a domain with Mandrill and sent a message to a fictional mailbox on that domain.  The server relayed the message--I can go on the Mandrill dashboard and see the SendRaw API call for the message.  I would like to retrieve the message from where-ever it is located...whether it is located on Mandrill's servers or whether it was sent to my domain where I needed to have something listening for the send, I don't know.  I'm very new at this (circa yesterday). Either way, I need to get that message.  Is it possible to do it using the API?

Or is Mandrill just relaying the message to my url when it is originally sent, and I need to set up the url to receive the message in order to get it?

Comment: Which line in the method is failing?

Comment: the API method...so I'm calling https://mandrillAPI.com/api/1.0/  and the method is "inbound/send-raw.json."  The response I get from the API is "validation error: You must specify a raw message value."  

I think it means that send-raw is for literally sending a raw message; but it is inbound/send-raw, so I thought it might send the message that was inbound...but it might actually be sending the raw message I specify.  Either way, I'd like to somehow retrieve the message that I sent...

Comment: Which line is calling the "API method" you are referring to?  Is it the 1st line (string declaration), 4th line (HttpResponsemessage declaration), or the 5th line (reading response)?

Comment: client.GetAsync(key) hits the API with the URL. There is no error in the code though.  The API request goes through and returns.  The content of the message indicates that I need to provide the raw message as an argument to the API call...however, what I'm trying to do is retrieve the message.  

I think I might have to set up some kind of HTTP listener on my domain that I have set up for inbound messages in order to get the content of the email...but I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inbound mail can't be retrieved through the Mandrill API. Inbound mail is received by Mandrill, converted to an [inbound/send-raw API call](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/inbound.JSON.html#method=send-raw), and then POSTed to the webhook that you've specified for your inbound route. Mandrill doesn't store the message contents for API retrieval. Once they're POSTed to your webhook URL, the message is discarded. Note that [inbound/send-raw](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/inbound.JSON.html#method=send-raw) is different than [messages/send-raw](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send-raw). The inbound/send-raw API call allows you to mimic what would happen if you sent a message to a route that you've set up (ie, POSTing to the webhook URL).

More information about how inbound mail works and the webhooks can be found in the Mandrill KB: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/categories/200277247-Inbound-Email-Processing

Comment: Thank you.  Ended up forwarding emails to a gmail using a route. Hopefully that work-around will delay dealing with the webhook for now.